# spring mvc html5mode angular not kicking in intercepting url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, spring, spring-mvc

So I have a mix between angular and spring mvc. I'm using spring and thymeleaf for certain pages of my website while I created a single page application with angular for the "/chart" page.

I set a controller which returns a chart.html for the "/chart" requests and forward to the same view for the "/chart/**" requests.

Everything's fine until I set the angular RouteProvider html5mode to true. After that angular is not kicking in anymore and every time I navigate to any url of the single page application the server is being called.

What's happening?

Is it fine?

I set the base url to "/". Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I was adding the header with the links BEFORE declaring ng-app="myApp".

Angular could not intercept those links.

I solved adding the ng-app at html tag level.
My bad.